# Unable to update metadata on the client side in Next.js by fetching data on the client side

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, seo

I am using `NextSeo` but unable to update metadata by fetching data on client side.

```
useEffect(()=>{
 fetch(assetURL)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data); 
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
  });
```

With NextSEO

```
   <NextSeo
          {...defaultSeoProp}
          title={data?.name ?? 'Asset Name'  }
          description={data?.description ?? ''}
          openGraph={{
            title: data?.name ?? '',
            description: data?.description ?? '',
            images: [{ url: data?.thumbnail ?? '', width: 270, height: 270 }],
          }}
        />
```

When I share the URL of a particular asset, crawlers only fetching default metadata not the updated one

Answer (score 0):

Actually, based on the Next.js documentation, you should use Metadata in **Server Components** because Metadata is the server's responsibility, not the client's.

I believe these links would be helpful:

[Server and Client Composition Patterns](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns)

[Metadata](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata)

Comment: Yea, but the project is built with ```next 12.1.6```. We also tried with ```getInitialProps``` and ```getServerSideProps``` but we experienced very slowness that took more time to render the page.

Comment: In this case, if you want to have dynamic metadata, I believe you should use `getServerSideProps` and avoid fetching data on the client side.


Regarding the part where you mentioned slowness, is this slowness also present in production?

Comment: Yea both in ```production``` and ```development```